I'm getting Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'react-dom/client'
My react versions  "react": "^18.3.1", "react-dom": "^18.3.1","react-router-dom": "^6.23.0"
I'm getting error when i update the above packages.
My Code
import React from 'react';
import {createRoot} from 'react-dom/client';
const root = createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(<NextApp />);


What versions are you updating to?
